# Cassandra row key starts with

Tags: cassandra, hector, astyanax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cassandra querying on a part of a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857471/cassandra-querying-on-a-part-of-a-key)

I have a cassandra column family which has a row key like 2012-09-30-05-42-00:30:5856869

I need to query some thing like

select * from cf where key like %2012-09-30-05-42-00:30:%
Currently I am using Astyanax , is same possible in astyanax. If not, which implementation would support it.